# WLC HA Pair Ip address when takeover

Tags: radius, aironet, cisco-wlc

I have a WLC HA Pair, and every appliance has it's own ip address. 
for example: 1.1.1.1 main node and 1.1.1.2 the secondary.
I have an SSID with AAA configured pointing to a NPS server which has the ip 2.2.2.2

My question is: if we are under the situation of switchover from main node to second one, the main ip (1.1.1.1) is assumed by the secondary node, so when trying to communicate to radius server, ¿the request is originated from 1.1.1.1 ip or the physical 1.1.1.2 which is his original ip?

This Q is because, in radius server, I need to configure each client who could initiate a connection against the NPS service. So in case of HA pair I don't know if i need to configure both nodes IP in authorized clients or only the main one IP.

In this moment, my environment is under production so is very complicated for me schedule a maintenance window to test only this, so if anyone who has an HA pair know this situation I will be very thankful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you put the tag of `aironet`, so that I assume you are using Cisco WLC.

I used to manage this kind of WLC HA and I can be sure that both WLCs share the same IP address (here is 1.1.1.1) as long as you configured them properly.

Cisco also states this in their [Cisco WLC Configuration Guide](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/controller/8-0/configuration-guide/b_cg80/b_cg80_chapter_01000.html):

> **Information About High Availability**
>
> ...
>
> The standby-hot controller
>   continuously monitors the health of the active controller through a
>   direct wired connection over a dedicated redundancy port. **Both the
>   controllers share the same configurations, including the IP address of
>   the management interface**

Therefore, you should be good with configuration for the IP 1.1.1.1 only.

If you want to be on the safe side, you can add both IPs until you have a downtime opportunity to perform a real test.,